# Erro ao salvar conteudo de TRichEdit Delphi no PostgresSQL

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Tenho que gravar textos formatados na base de dados PostgreSQL, quando eu carrego o RichEdit mostra o texto normal, mas quando salvo e vou olhar na base de dados os caracteres etão assim:

> 屻瑲ㅦ慜獮屩湡楳灣ㅧ㔲尲敤晦笰晜湯瑴汢屻て晜睳獩屳灦煲尲捦慨獲瑥‰慃楬牢㭩筽晜就湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬳筽晜尲湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬵筽晜尳湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬴筽晜尴湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬷筽晜尵湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬸筽晜尶湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ䌠䑉潆瑮䘫㬶筽晜尷湦汩晜档牡敳ぴ吠桡浯㭡絽਍屻潣潬瑲汢㬠牜摥㔲尵牧敥㉮㔵扜畬㉥㔵尻敲㡤尹牧敥㡮尹汢敵㤸尻敲㕤尴牧敥㥮尵汢敵㐱㬶牜摥尰牧敥の扜畬づ尻敲㕤就牧敥㕮就汢敵ㄵ尻敲つ杜敲湥尰汢敵㔲㬵ൽ尊楶睥楫摮尴捵就慰摲煜屪慬杮〱㘴晜尰獦㠱传䰠䍔

Na base de dados eu uso UTF-8 e no cliente LATIN1, tudo funciona normal menos o RichEdit

Estou sem parametro pra resolver esse problema

Segue parte do código para melhor entendimento de como os dados entram na base, a parte em questão é no `if (fdm.Salvar)...`

```
  if (zqrOrcItens.RecordCount = 0) then
  begin
    TFuncoes.pMensagem('Não existem itens na lista para editar');
    Exit;
  end;
  fdm.Salvar := False;
  fdm.RichStream := TStringStream.Create(zqrOrcItensTexto.AsAnsiString);
  //zqrOrcItensTexto.SaveToStream(fdm.RichStream);

  f_richedit := Tf_richedit.Create(nil);
  fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
  f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);
  TFuncoes.pJustRichEdit(f_richedit.RichEdit, False);
  f_richedit.ShowModal;

  if (fdm.Salvar) then
  begin
    zqrOrcItens.Edit;
    fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
    zqrOrcItensTexto.AsString := fdm.RichStream.DataString;
    zqrOrcItenstexto_puro.AsString := fdm.TextoPuro;
    zqrOrcItens.Post;
    fdm.zConecta.Commit;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(fdm.RichStream);
```

RichStream é uma variável TStringStream que esta dentro de um datamodule para ser vista em vários pontos da aplicação.

A ideia é criar uma variável do tipo TStringStream para receber o conteúdo do RichEdit e converter em caractere aceitável pelo PostgreSQL

**Importante:** Essa rotina foi feita a muito tempo com versões antigas do Delphi, PostgreSQL e Zeos e na época foi a única forma que consegue inserir conteúdo de RichEdit na base e visualizar de maneira compreensível.

Comment: posta parte do código que utiliza para enviar o conteúdo do `TRichEdit` para o banco.

Comment: Se colocar um `breakpoint` o que da para ler aqui: `zqrOrcItensTexto.AsString := fdm.RichStream.DataString;`?

Comment: Mostra o texto do RichEdit com os caracteres de formatação tipo: ***{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1046\fs20 teste\par
}*** ou seja, mostra o conteúdo correto a ser gravado, pois ele deve realmente ter essa formatação, mas quando cai no banco e vou olhar lá estão os caracteres da china, rsrs, é alguma coisa entre o Zeos e o PostgreSQL pelo que vejo. Eu vou testar outra versão do Zeos pra ver, vai que é algum bug...

Answer (score -1):

Talvez TMemoField(zqrOrcItensTexto).LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);
no lugar de zqrOrcItensTexto.AsString := fdm.RichStream.DataString;

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).